# Was genau bedeutet "Akademiker"?

Tags: meaning

Ich habe einen Artikel gelesen, aber ich wusste nicht genau, was *Akademiker* bedeutet.

Ist es jemand, der einen Hochschulabschluss geschafft hat? Oder jemand, der einen Doktortitel erhält?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ein Akademiker ist entweder jemand, der

- einen Hochschulabschluss hat, oder
- an eine Akademie der Wissenschaften gewählt wurde.

Unter Hochschulabschluss fallen alle Abschlüsse durch bestandenes Examen.

Comment: Siehe auch: http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Akademiker

Comment: @Em1 Danke für den Edit, verfluchte automatische Großschreibung <.<

Comment: Im alltäglichen Gebrauch ist eindeutig die erste Option dominant, also eine Person mit Hochschulabschluss (Universität)

Comment: Würde man einen Bachelor als Akademiker bezeichnen? Ich würde mich dagegen sträuben, weil ich aus Studienrichtungen komme, in denen der Bachelor eben kein vollwertiger berufsbefähigender Abschluss ist. D.h. die Menschen, die nur Bachelor haben, werden noch als Studenten oder Studienabbrecher gesehen.

Comment: @Toscho In welchen Richtungen ist es so? Ich kenne Akademiker wirklich als alle, die mit Examen abgeschlossen haben, so weit bin ich aber nicht, dass ich da komplett die Situation beim Bachelor kenne.

Comment: Lehramt, Mathematik, Physik (als Verallgemeinerung aller Naturwissenschaften)

Comment: Akademiker ist jeder mit Hochschulabschluss, das habe ich noch nie anders gehört. Wenn einzelne Fachbereiche da Bachelors intern nicht hinzurechnen sei ihnen das als persöhnliche Befindlichkeit unbenommen, rechtlich ist ein Bachelor aber ein vollwertiger Abschluss (und hier das Fass Bolognia-Prozess aufzumachen geht dann doch zu weit). Und das sage ich als "Diplomer" :)

Comment: @Toscho: Ich bin Bachelor of Science in Engineering und habe diesen Hochschulabschluss mit Auszeichnung an einer österreichischen Fachhochschule (also *nicht* an einer Universität) gemacht. Ich fühle mich durchaus als Akademiker und dem Gesetz nach bin ich auch tatsächlich einer.

Comment: @HubertSchölnast Genau das habe ich mit meinem Kommentar auszudrücken versucht: Es hängt von der Studienrichtung ab. Ein BSc in Engineering mag ein Akademiker sein (kann ich nicht einschätzen), ein BSc im Lehramt ist es garantiert nicht und ein BSc in Mathematik wird auch nicht universell als Akademiker sondern teilweise noch als Student angesehen.

Comment: @Toscho: Auch wenn es dir nicht gefällt: Wer als Lehramtsstudent den Bachelor macht ist Akademiker. Wer Mathematik studiert und dabei den Bachelor macht ist ebenfalls Akademiker. Es ist nicht verboten als Akademiker weiter zu studieren. In einem Post-Graduate-Studium ist das sogar eine Voraussetzung, und jedes Master-Studium ist ein Post-Graduate-Studium.

Comment: @HubertSchölnast Es geht nicht darum, was derjenige noch damit macht, sondern was er bisher erreicht hat bzw. welche Kompetenzen er bisher erworben hat. In den von mir genannten Bereichen ist die Sichtweise häufig, dass ein Bachelor eben noch nicht genug erreicht / erworben für einen *inhaltlich sinnvollen* Abschluss hat, auch wenn er Formal ein Zeugnis hat. Ich hatte während des Studiums auch ein Zeugnis über bestandene Zwischenprüfung erhalten. Damit war ich aber auch noch kein Akademiker.

Comment: @Toscho: Du hast das richtige Wort verwendet: »formal«. Wer vor dem Bolognia-Prozess den ersten Abschnitt eines Magister-Studiums »abgeschlossen« hat, hat keinen echten Abschluss gemacht. Er hat keinen akademischen Grad erworben und ist dadurch nicht zum Akademiker geworden. Jetzt hat man damit einen formalen Abschluss und ein gesetzlich gültigen akademischen Grad erworben. Damit ist man ganz offiziell Akademiker. Es geht also weder darum was man damit zukünftig machen kann, noch welche Kompetenzen man bisher erworben hat. Es geht nur um das Stück Papier auf dem steht dass man Akademiker ist.

Comment: @HubertSchölnast Zeig mir bitte ein solches Dokument, auf dem steht, dass man „Akademiker“ sei. Dort steht „Bachelor of hastenichtgesehen“. `Akademiker` ist kein festgesetzter geschweige denn justiziabler Begriff.

Comment: @Toscho Möglicherweise überzeugt dich ein Schrieb der Bundesregierung, was ein *akademischer Grad* ist (wer einen solchen besitzt, ist wohl per Definition *Akademiker*). Dort ist u.A. der Bachelor explizit aufgeführt: https://www.protokoll-inland.de/Webs/PI/DE/anschriften-anreden/akademische-grade/akademische-grade_amtsbezeichnungen-node.html#:~:text=Akademische%20Grade%20werden%20in%20Deutschland,durch%20Aushändigung%20einer%20Urkunde%20verliehen.&text=Akademische%20Grade%20sind%20hauptsächlich%20%22Diplom,Master%22%20und%20%22Doktor%22%20.

Answer (score 3):

Die Antworten von looper und embert sind zwar richtig, aber es geht einfacher:

**Jeder, dem ein akademischer Grad verliehen wurde, ist ein Akademiker.**

Ganz so einfach ist es in der Praxis dann aber doch nicht, denn nun hat man das Problem erkennen zu müssen was eine Berufsbezeichnung, was ein Titel und was ein akademischer Grad ist. (Falls das unklar sein sollte: Akademische Grade sind keine Titel!)

### Titel

Es gibt Adelstitel, Berufstitel, Amtstitel und kirchliche Titel. Wer nur einen Titel, aber keinen akademischen Grad hat, ist **kein** Akademiker!

**Adelstitel** kennzeichnen den Rang in der Adelshierarchie. Adelstitel werden vererbt. Wer österreichischer Staatsbürger ist darf seit 1919 keinen Adelstitel führen. Ähnliche Adelsverbote gibt es in fast allen ehemaligen europäischen Monarchien. Deutschland ist eine Ausnahme: In der Weimarer Verfassung (ebenfalls von 1919) wurde festgelegt, dass Adelstitel Bestandteile des Namens sind und auch weiterhin geführt werden dürfen. In der Schweiz wurden Adelstitel schon im 18. Jahrhundert verboten.

Darunter fallen beispielsweise: Kaiser, König, Fürst, Herzog, Baron, usw.

**Berufstitel** gibt es nur in Österreich. Das sind Auszeichnungen die man für langjährige Ausübung eines bestimmten Berufes vom Bundespräsidenten verliehen bekommt. Diese Titel werden auf Lebenszeit verliehen, das heißt man darf sie auch nach Beendigung der aktiven Laufbahn weiterführen.

Darunter fallen beispielsweise: Hofrat, Ökonomierat, Bergrat honoris causa, Kammersänger, aber auch Professor und Universitätsprofessor.

Davon zu unterscheiden sind gesetzlich geschützte Amts- und Berufsbezeichnungen, die nicht vom Bundespräsidenten verliehen werden und die es auch in Deutschland gibt. Wer eine geschützte Berufsbezeichnung führt ohne tatsächlich den bezeichneten Beruf auszuüben macht sich strafbar. (Beispiele: Architekt, Zivilingeneur, Tierarzt, Rechtsanwalt). In Deutschland fällt auch der »Professor« in die gesetzlich geschützten Berufsbezeichnungen.

**Amtstitel** gibt es auch nur in Österreich. Sie sind mit der Ausübung eines Amtes verbunden und können daher nur von Beamten getragen werden. Durch Beendigung der beruflichen Tätigkeit erlischt der Amtstitel automatisch. Österreichische Amtstitel entsprechen im wesentlichen den Amtsbezeichnungen in Deutschland, die dort aber keine Titel sind, sondern zu den gesetzlich geschützten Amts- und Berufsbezeichnungen gehören.

Darunter fallen beispielsweise: Amtsrat, Fachoberinspektor, Botschafter, ...

**kirchliche Titel** werden von der katholischen Kirche an Priester verliehen.

Darunter falle beispielsweise: Prälat, Bischof, Kardinal, Apostolischer Nuntius, ...

### akademische Grade

**Akademische Grade** sind Auszeichnungen, die man nach einer mehrjährigen Ausbildung an einer Hochschule nach erfolgreich bestandener Abschlussprüfung verliehen bekommt. Daher ist insbesondere die Bezeichnung "Professor" *kein* akademischer Grad, da man dafür keine gesonderte Ausbildung machen muss und auch keine Prüfung ablegen muss. Wer nur Professor ist ohne einen anderen akademischen Grad zu haben ist kein Akademiker. (Ein Beispiel: Der österreichische Sänger Udo Jürgens, der seit 2007 auch Schweizer Staatsbürger ist, hat nie eine Hochschule besucht, trägt seit 1984 aber den vom österreichischen Bundespräsidenten verliehenen Titel »Professor«. Er ist Professor, aber kein Akademiker)

Der Bachelor ist hingegen ganz ausdrücklich ein akademischer Grad, da er genau der obigen Definition entspricht. (Abschluss eines Hochschulstudiums durch eine bestandene Prüfung.)

Wichtig ist auch, dass man die Ausbildung und die Prüfung an einer Hochschule absolviert. Zu den Hochschulen gehören beispielsweise Universitäten, Fachhochschulen, Fernuniversitäten,  Musikhochschulen, Pädagogische Hochschulen, usw.

Keine Hochschulen sind hingegen Volkshochschulen, Wirtschaftsakademien und Berufsakademien. Wer dort eine Ausbildung und einen Abschluss macht ist »Diplom-Irgendwas« oder »diplomierter Irgendwas« wobei »Irgendwas« für eine Berufsbezeichnung steht (Volkswirt, Ziviltechniker, Wirtschaftsinformatiker, usw.). Diese Bezeichnungen sind weder akademische Grade noch Titel (auch nicht in Österreich) sondern einfache Berufsbezeichnungen.

---

### Besonderheiten

### Ingenieur, Diplom-Ingenieur

Etwas aus dem Ramen fallen die Bezeichnungen »Ingenieur« und »Diplom-Ingenieur«.

**Ingenieur**
Den Berufstitel »Ingenieur« bekommt man in Österreich wenn man eine Höherer Technische Lehranstalt (HTL) absolviert hat und anschließend drei Jahre lang einschlägig beruflich tätig war. Dem entspricht in Deutschland der »staatlich geprüfte Techniker«. Damit ist der österreichische Ingenieur *kein* Akademiker, denn eine HTL ist keine Hochschule.

Die Situation in Deutschland ist mir leider nicht geläufig, ich vermute aber, dass auch dort der einfache Ingenieur kein Akademiker ist.

**Diplom-Ingenieur**
Der »Diplom-Ingenieur« ist hingegen ein Akademiker, denn diesen akademischen Grad erlangt man durch Abschluss eines Hochschulstudiums.

### Doktor honoris causa (Dr. h.c.)

Dass der Professor (egal ob mit dem Zusatz »h.c.« oder ohne) kein akademischer Grad ist, sollte aus dem oben gesagten bereits klar sein. Aber auch der Titel »Dr. h.c.« ist kein akademischer Grad. Denn diese Ehrenbezeichnung wird aufgrund besonderer Verdienste verliehen und setzt keinen Hochschulabschluss voraus. Der »Dr. h.c.« ist auch kein Titel und auch keine Berufsbezeichnung. Diese Bezeichnung darf daher auch nicht als Bestandteil des Namens (z.B. auf Visitenkarten, Türschildern, auf einem Briefkopf,...) geführt werden.

Es gibt kirchliche Institutionen, die einen gegen eine Spende von ca. 50 Euro zum »Doktor honoris causa« ernennen. Man kauft damit ein hübsch bedrucktes Blatt Papier, das man daheim im Wohnzimmer an die Wand hängen darf, erwirbt damit aber keine weiteren Rechte.

Comment: Es ist ja schön, dass es eine einfachere Definition gäbe, das hilft aber nicht, wenn das Wort auch anders gebraucht wird.

Comment: Ein Diplom-Ingenieur ist in Deutschland ein anerkannter akademischer Grad. Ausser, er hat eine Berufs*akademie* (sic) besucht, dann ist sein Diplom-Ingenieur(BA) keiner. Das hat seinen Grund darin, dass alle von einer *Hochschule* verliehenen Titel als akademische Grade gelten und *vom Staat* verliehene (das ist beim BA so, die Berufsakademie ist keine Hochschule) eben nicht.

Comment: Im Gegensatz zu Österreich darf man in Deutschland die Berufs- (oder Standes-)bezeichnung "Ingenieur" seit den 70ern nur noch führen, wenn man ein Studium der Ingenieurwissenschaften abgeschlossen hat.

Comment: wie sieht es mit bestandenen Staatsexamina aus (zB Medizin, Jura)? Kein akademischer Grad, aber dennoch Akademiker?

Comment: Auch der Dr. ist kein Bestandteil des Namens. Ich bezweifle außerdem, dass Dr. h.c. nicht auf einer Visitenkarte stehen darf. Nur das h.c. darf eben nicht weggelassen werden.

Answer (score 2):

The following list shows what is referred as **`Akademiker`** (from most to less frequent occurrence):

> - Personen mit Hochschulabschluss
> - das wissenschaftliche Personal an einer Hochschule
> - ein Akademiemitglied in einer Akademie der Wissenschaften
> - Mitglieder bestimmter anderer Gesellschaften der wissenschaftlichen Förderung, siehe Gelehrtengesellschaft
> - die Mitglieder der altgriechischen Philosophenschule Platonische Akademie
> - ein vom finnischen Staatspräsidenten vergebener Ehrentitel, dem Akateemikko, deutsch: Akademiker, ab 1970 geteilt in Akademiker der Wissenschaft und Akademiker der Kunst
>     <sub>http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Akademiker</sub>