# Grußformel zwischen „Sehr geehrte(r)“ und „Liebe(r)“

Tags: formality, salutation

Ich verfasse gerade eine E-Mail nach Deutschland, aber bin bereits an der Anrede hängengeblieben. Die/der Empfänger(in) habe ich nie getroffen, aber eine Wirtschaftsbrief sollte es nicht werden. **Was macht man eigentlich, wenn sich *Sehr geehrte(r) …* als zu formell  und *Liebe(r) …* als nur total unpassend anfühlt?** Auf Englisch ist es ja schon sehr einfach, da nutzt man ja immer nur *Hi* oder *Hello* und so auch auf meiner eigenen Muttersprache.

In anderen Threads habe ich *Guten Tag* gefunden. Ist diese Anrede in einer nicht-beruflichen quasi-formellen Konversation, in denen man der/die Empfänger(in) nicht kennt, üblich? Oder gibt es überhaupt diese Situationen, in denen keine der beiden Standard-Anreden passt? Scheint uns Fremden *Sehr geehrte(r) …* nur viel formeller als es eigentlich ist?

Comment: Wenn Du auf Englisch „Hallo“ schreibst, kannst Du das auf deutsch auch tun (was nicht heißt, dass ich das angemessen finde ;). Es ist aber eine sehr gute Frage, auch als Muttersprachler finde ich das manchmal schwierig.

Comment: Manche schreiben auch _Sehr geehrter, lieber Herr X_. :-)

Comment: Ich habe deine Fehler ausgebessert. Sie waren durchgehend (in meinen Augen) geringfügig, wie eine falsche Auseinanderschreibung (*hängengeblieben*) oder ab und an ein falscher Fall/falsches grammatikalisches Geschlecht. Dort, wo ich Sätze umgestellt habe, war deine Variante nicht falsch aber unüblich. Und statt *wo* sollte man besser *in denen* o.ä. schreiben, wenn es sich nicht um einen geographischen Ort handelt (und selbst dann immer wieder).

Comment: (Zumindest) hier in Österreich ist "Hallo Herr xyz" bzw. "Hallo Frau xyz" eine sehr gebräuchliche Form, eine E-Mail zu beginnen, die weder zu förmlich noch zu freundschaftlich ist.

Comment: @Jan Vielen Dank für die Korrektur und Danke auch zu alle anderen! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wenn der Brief an einen gewissen *Hofrat Dr. Franz Geiger* gerichtet ist, gibt es diese Anreden, wobei ganz oben die förmlichste Anrede und unten die informellste steht:

- Sehr geehrter Herr Hofrat* Dr. Franz Geiger,
- Sehr geehrter Herr Hofrat Dr. Geiger,
- Sehr geehrter Herr Hofrat Geiger,
- Sehr geehrter Herr Geiger,
- Lieber Herr Geiger,
- Lieber Franz,
- Hallo/Servus** Franz,
- Hallo!

*) »Hofrat« ist in Österreich ein Amtstitel, der als Bestandteil des Namens Teil einer förmlichen Anrede ist. Nähere Informationen darüber was in welchem Land ein Titel oder Grad ist, und ob es Teil des Namens ist, gibt es hier: https://german.stackexchange.com/a/13746/1487

**) »Servus» ist nur in Österreich ein gängiger Gruß, in anderen Regionen kann man stattdessen einen beliebigen anderen freundschaftlichen Gruß verwenden.

Wie man sieht., steht zwischen den beiden nachgefragten Formen »Sehr geehrter Herr Geiger« und »Lieber Franz« die Anrede »Lieber Herr Geiger«. Sie beginnt mit der informellen und freundschaftlichen Anrede »Lieber«, spricht den Adressaten aber mit Geschlechtsbezeichnung und Nachnamen an, was wieder einen gewissen formellen Aspekt einbringt. Somit dürften

> Lieber Herr *Nachname*
>   Liebe Frau *Nachname*

die Lösungen des Problems sein.

Comment: In Deutschland wird der **Doktortitel fester Bestandteil des Namens** und darf in einer förmlichen Anrede auf gar keinen Fall fehlen. Wenn Herr Geiger promoviert ist, muss die Anrede "Lieber/Sehr geehrter [Herr] **Dr.** Geiger" lauten. Nur promovierte Akademiker, die sich kennen, aber Siezen, schreiben sich unteinander auch mit "Lieber Herr Geiger" an.

Comment: @Takkat Wann wurde dieses Urteil den aufgehoben? `[...]Die Meinung des Klägers, daß der Doktortitel nach Gewohnheitsrecht als Bestandteil des Namens zu gelten habe, trifft nicht zu.[...]` [Bundesverwaltungsgericht
Urt. v. 24.10.1957, Az.: BVerwG I C 50.56](https://www.jurion.de/Urteile/BVerwG/1957-10-24/BVerwG-I-C-5056)

Comment: @t.niese IANAL aber das Gesetz gilt noch immer, d.h. du hast keinen Rechtsanspruch auf Eintragung deines Titels, aber im derzeit gültigen Gesetz darfst du ihn als Namensbestandteil, auch im Pass und bei der Meldebehörde, führen. Du darfst ihn freilich auch weglassen, wenn du möchtest. Bei einem formellen Anschreiben (nur darum geht es hier) an eine unbekannte Person sollte man den Titel aber nicht weglassen.

Comment: @Takkat: Hier geht es eben ausdrücklich **nicht** um ein formelles Anschreiben. Der OP schwankt zwischen »Sehr geehrter« und »Lieber«. Wenn »Lieber« in Erwägung gezogen wird, und »Sehr geehrter« offenbar zu steif klingt, kann es sich nicht um ein formelles Anschreiben handeln. Insofern ist dein Hinweis, dass ein akademischer Grad (»Doktor« ist **kein** Titel sondern ein Grad, siehe http://german.stackexchange.com/a/13746/1487) ein Bestandteil des Namens ist, zwar richtig, aber irrelevant. Auch der Nachname ist Bestandteil des Namens, aber niemand zwingt mich, ihn zu »Hallo Franz« hinzuzufügen.

Comment: @HubertSchölnast: in konkreten Fall ist es sowieso egal, denn der Angeschriebene ist vermutlich weder Hofrat noch promoviert, aber wenn Du schon so ein Beispiel wählst, dann bitte nicht *Sehr geehrter Herr Geiger*, das geht nicht, wenn es ein Herr **Dr.** Geiger ist. Ich kann mir kaum vorstellen, dass das in Österreich anders ist.

Comment: @Takkat: Meine beiden Bachelorarbeiten habe ich bei Priv.-Doz. Mag.rer.soc.oec. Dipl.-Ing. Dipl.-Ing. Dr.techn. Karl Michael Göschka geschrieben (siehe http://i4c.at/goeschka/ unter »Students« - »Completed Theses« wirst du zweimal meinen Namen finden). Wenn ich bei jedem E-Mail, das ich ihm geschrieben habe, in der Anrede seine ganzen Titel und Grade hingeschrieben hätte, wäre ich kaum rechtzeitig mit meiner Arbeit fertig geworden. Zwischen ihm und seinen Studenten galt die Abmachung, auf Titel in der Anrede zu verzichten. Also habe ich immer nur »Sehr geehrter Herr Göschka« geschrieben.

Comment: @HubertSchölnast: jetzt hast Du mich verwirrt. Man kann also in einem Anschreiben in Österreich alle Titel weglassen, auch wenn man die Person noch gar nicht kennt? Wenn das so ist, dann solltest Du in Deiner Antwort darauf hinweisen. In Deutschland sind wir noch nicht so weit.

Comment: @Takkat: Nein, natürlich schreibt man eine fremde Person nicht so an. Aber der Fragesteller scheint den Adressaten ja zu kennen, sonst würde er wohl kaum darüber nachdenken, ob »Lieber ...« passen könnte. Er hat nur geschrieben, dass er den Adressaten noch nicht persönlich getroffen hat. Ich habe dich auch noch nie getroffen, und kenne dich trotzdem ein wenig. Gut genug jedenfalls, um dich hier zu duzen, und um auf eine Auflistung deiner Titel und Grade (falls du welche hast) in einer E-Mail-Anrede zu verzichten.

Comment: Eigentlich finde ich hier spannend, wie man in Österreich vefährt, wenn der *Hofrat* ins Spiel kommt. In D würde man bei Anrede *Sehr geehrter* nicht auf den Dr. verzichten können, vermute aber dass der *Hofrat Geiger* in Österreich auch ohne Dr. geht. Vielleicht geht es auch nicht, den Herrn Dr. Geiger "nur" als Dr. zu betiteln, wenn er auch Hofrat ist...?

Comment: Takkat: In Deutschland gab es dafür lange Zeit noch immer Adelstitel, die in Österreich seit dem Ende der Monarchie (1919) verboten sind. (Die letzten Adelstitel in Deutschland wurden 1918 verliehen und blieben bis zum Tod gültig. Da nun alle, die einen solchen Titel hatten, mittlerweile verstorben sein dürften, hat auch in Deutschland niemand mehr einen rechtsgültigen Adelstitel)

Answer (score 3):

Ich hatte dein Problem lange Zeit und habe generell *Sehr geehrter Herr Hubermayr* als Rückfallebene benutzt.

Allerdings beginnt mein Chef (der auf ein *Sie* besteht, und ungehalten wird, wenn er mitbekommt, dass wir über ihn reden, indem wir nur seinen Nachnamen ohne *Herr* verwenden – der also eher dem konservativeren Menschenschlag zuzurechnen ist) alle seine E-Mails, soweit ich sie zu Gesicht bekommen habe, mit *Lieber Herr Hubermayr.* Dementsprechend kann man das jederzeit als Grußformel verwenden, auch wenn es auf den ersten Blick intimer wirkt.

Vergleiche mit Englisch, wo *dear* sowohl im formellen als auch im informellen Kontext die korrekte Grußformel ist.

Answer (score 2):

Auch im geschäftlichen Umfeld ist Hallo Frau/Herr XY absolut üblich. Alle externen Firmen reden uns so an - und wir sie. Ob wir uns schon mal gesehen haben oder nicht ist egal. In einem internationalen Konzern mit dem ich mal zu tun hatte, war "Vorname," also ohne jede Anrede üblich (Mails waren immer Englisch). Das habe ich bisher aber nur dort mitbekommen. Innerhalb einer Firma heißt es oft "Hallo Vorname," oder einfach nur "Hi," falls man sich mit du anredet. Ansonsten würde ich meinen Chef in einem eher informellem Umfeld auch mit "Hallo Herr X," anreden.